# Banach's fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point, fixed-points

For the following question, we are to use Banach's fixed point theorem to show that $\{x_n\}$ converges to the root of the polynomial: $x^4 - 4x^2 - x + 4 = 0$ ; lying between $\sqrt{3}$ and $2$. Let ${x_1} =  \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt {2 + \sqrt{x_n}}$.

I know the theorem states that if $f: X \to X$ is a contraction of a complete metric space X, then f has a unique fixed point.

I think I need to prove that f has a contraction, but I don't quite understand how to proceed with that. Is that the right approach or is there another approach that would be more efficient, per se.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X=[\sqrt{3},2]$ and $f(x)= \sqrt {2 + \sqrt{x}}$. $X$ is a complete metric space.

Show that $f(X) \subset X$ and that there is $q \in (0,1)$ such that  $|f'(x)| \le q$ for all $x \in X$. By the mean value theorem:

$|f(x)-f(y)| \le q|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Hence there is $x \in X$ with $f(x)=x$.

But: $f(x)=x \iff x^4 - 4x^2 - x + 4 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Guide** Set $X := [\sqrt{3},2]$ as your complete metric space, and set $f(x) := \sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}$. Use Calculus to see that $f$ is increasing, and a self-map on $X$. Moreover, $f'$ is positive and decreasing on $X$. Since $f'(\sqrt{3})<1$, the Mean Value Theorem guarantees that $f$ is a Banach contraction on $X$. Hence your sequence will converge to the unique fixed point.